# Adding labels to map data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, r-sf

So based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124829/error-plotting-nyc-boroughs-using-osm-in-r), I created a map of the boroughs of NY using ggplot

I have a data set which looks like this, called `boroughs_personal`

```
borough    count
Brooklyn     211
Manhattan     12
Queens         1
```

So I join this to the map data similarly to the post above and it works like a dream.

```
# download and extract data
bb <- getbb("New York City, New York")

boundaries <- opq(bbox = bb) %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  unname_osmdata_sf()

boroughs <- boundaries[["osm_multipolygons"]] %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Manhattan", "The Bronx", "Brooklyn", "Queens", "Staten Island")) %>% 
  left_join(boroughs_personal , by = c('name' = 'borough'))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = boroughs, aes(fill = count))+
  ##guides(fill=FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
  ggtitle('New York Boroughs ')
```

But I need to add the labels of the `count` variable to each borough. How can I do this???

Comment: [`ggplot2::geom_sf_text`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html)

Comment: `geom_sf_text(aes(label = count), colour = "white")` I tried this but to no avail @camille

Comment: Why? What happens? It would be helpful to see what you're looking at without having to install & download everything

Comment: @camille here's the error `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): label = count. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider moving the `data` and `aes()` declarations from your geom_sf to the main ggplot function. The `geom_sf_label()` will then know where to look for your data object.

An alternative would be having both data and aes in each of the geom_sf_* calls - but this is unnecessary, as both the labels and fills are based on the same data object.

```
  ggplot(data = boroughs, aes(fill = count, 
                            label = count)) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf_label(fill = "white",  # override the fill from aes()
                fun.geometry = sf::st_centroid) + # make Manhattan behave itself
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "lightblue", 
                        high = "darkblue") +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(), 
        axis.text=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks=element_blank()) + 
  ggtitle('New York Boroughs ')
```

[image: new york with labels, with Manhattan behaving itself]

Comment: this is CLOSE! My only issue, is there a way to get 12 better onto Manhattan? As opposed to being so far left ?

Comment: I noticed that also, but as placing of the label is really a separate issue I did not wish to combine it; but since you mentioned it... see the updated code & picture. For the reference: the default label placement function is `sf::st_point_on_surface()`, which guarantees placement inside a polygon; in this case it does not quite work for Manhattan, and so `sf::st_centroid()` - which places the label in center of the polygon - is more appropriate. Should this fail you can always use nudge_x and nudge_y to finetune.

Comment: On second thought: the default label placement function picked Ellis Island as the "point on surface" for Manhattan, which is kinda sweet... :D